# Tell gcc compiler to treat variable not as constant when optimizing

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compilation, compiler-options

Is there any way to tell the compiler (here gcc) that it should not optimize variables that it thinks are constants to constant expressions? In general by a compiler flag or even better by using an attribute for a specific variable?

I want the (local) variable to really exist, every read on this variable to be actually executed and also every write, even if I write the same value again.

It would always load/store the variable from/to RAM if I don't optimize. Same if I declare it volatile. However, I do want it to be able to be kept in a register, just like a normal variable that's neither constant nor volatile. Disabling optimization completely is also not an option.

Code example (r(a) and r(b) are any register):
    int a, b;
    a = 2;
    a = 2;
    b = a;
Result (provided b is needed later, a no more):
    Ignored line
    Ignored line
    Moves 2 in r(b)
a is replaced by constant expression 2

```
volatile int a;  
int b;  
a = 2;  
a = 2;  
b = a;
```

Result (b is needed later, a doesn't matter):
    Moves 2 in r2, puts address of a in r3, writes r2 to RAM(r3)
    Writes r2 again to RAM(r3)
    Reads RAM(r3) into r4
    Puts address of b in r5, writes r4 to RAM(r5)

As you can see this is very inefficient. What I want:
    Move 2 in r(a)
    Move 2 in r(a) again
    Write r(a) into r(b)
    If registers are needed for something else, store a and b in RAM
This is exactly what would happen, if a was a real variable and not just 2.

Comment: `-O0` will remove all optimizations. Note that it's maybe standard to do this optimization so GCC will do it what ever. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you want that? The effect should not even be observable (if the var is in a register)?

Comment: Because the variable will never be kept in a register then, it would have to be loaded from RAM every time.

Comment: `volatile` doesn't necessarily imply that a variable cannot be put into a register. From a C standard point of view, it doesn't say *anything* about where it can be stored. You can even specify a variable to be `register volatile`, if you want

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the variable can change in the RAM at any time and thus must be reloaded every time? At least in my code it does

Comment: Post your code, if you want to demonstrate something. But I think this is a *very* premature optimization.

Comment: @Apache00 if in your code variables used in C can change while your C program is running, you have a serious concurrency problem. That should only happen for memory that is mapped to some device, or in a multi-processor system. In the latter case: Read a book on concurrent programming.

Comment: `register volatile` doesn't really imply it should be stored in RAM, doesn't it? You cannot *force* a variable to go into a register, though. `register`is only a hint.

Comment: You could maybe help us answering your question by specifiying what you want to achieve. I cannot, at the moment see any reason why you'd want to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's not so simple actually. I'm injecting random errors into the CPU. That's why it needs to be a variable I can manipulate (in Hardware), I cannot manipulate the ROM where the code and thus the constant expression is stored. Then I test a countermeasure that will automatically reload the variables (using a constant expression), if an error is detected. Could be done with the RAM value but would be too inefficient, as it's not just one variable.

Comment: @tofro I meant without the "register", it has no effect anyway in my code anyway, like you say.

Comment: Added example code, so you can see what I mean (no idea why it doesn't format correctly)

Comment: I'd be interested in how you want to inject an error value into a CPU register - That would be nearly as hard as doing it in a ROM...

Answer (score 1):

For such a demand you could not use C for this. It is not possible to dictate a variables physical location (RAM vs registry). The whole point of GCC is to take care of that for you.

You'd have to write your own assembly code to work with using load operations.

Comment: I don't want to dictate, but if I use volatile, I will dictate it to use RAM. What it does is an optimization, so it should be able to be disabled, I just don't know how?

Comment: @Apache00 no, you don't dictate that; it's not that easy. See John Bollinger's answer.

Comment: But can I somehow disable this specific optimization (to replace vars by constant expressions)? It is disabled, when I disable all optimization, so I should be able to disable only this one somehow. I have looked here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html but this are hundreds of options and i barely understand them. One of them might be responsible for this.

Answer (score 1):

Neither C nor GCC has a mechanism for what you describe.  The closest is to declare the variable `volatile`, which has the following effect:

> [...] any expression referring to [a `volatile`] object shall be **evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine**, as described in 5.1.2.3.  Furthermore, at every sequence point the value last stored in the object shall agree with that prescribed by the abstract machine, except as modified by the unknown  factors  mentioned  previously.

(C2011, 6.7.3/7; emphasis added)

It is primarily the highlighted part that bears on the question, for it requires reads and writes to the stored value of the variable actually be performed.  It does not necessarily prevent the variable from being allocated to a register, as the standard has nothing whatever to say about CPU registers, but it may be that it has that effect in some implementations.  (I cannot speak directly to GCC's behavior in that regard.)

Comment: @Apache00, Have you considered that the compiler might think there are more efficient uses for the available registers than to allocate your variable to one of them?  You could consider also declaring the variable to have `register` storage class if you never take its address, but that's just a hint -- the compiler is not obliged to treat it any differently than `auto`.

Comment: I understand, but in my code it always compiles to a RAM load, even with O3 and the variable written directly before. How could I disable that it's forced to do so? Assembler code looks like
    5a24: d4 01 28 00  l.sw 0(r1),r5
    5a28: a8 c6 42 40  l.ori r6,r6,0x4240 (something else)
    5a2c: c0 14 30 00  l.mtspr r20,r6,0x0 (something else)
    5a30: 84 61 00 00  l.lwz r3,0(r1)
Obviously the value is already in r5 (r1 is the stack pointer)

Comment: @Apache00, if the compiler indeed does allocate the variable in RAM, then it being `volatile` means that it must be read from / written to RAM on every access.  If it is allocated to a register, then not.  As I already answered, there is no way in C or a GCC extension to C to specify exactly what you seem to be asking for.  As other commenters have remarked, it's unclear why you want that.

Comment: register didn't change anything, if I used correctly: register volatile float* volatile pointer = (float*) addr;

Comment: Ah I understand, it would occupy the register the whole execution time then

Answer (score 1):

> It would always load/store the variable from/to RAM if I don't optimize.

no, that's not how CPUs or compilers work.

While C, at least for externally visible objects, guarantees that an non-temporary object has a comparable address <sup>citation needed</sup>, there's absolutely no reason for a compiler to generate from the following C code:

```
int a,b;
a = 0;
b = a + 2; 
a = 3;
```

any assembler that would, everytime you touch `a`, load a from RAM and store it back to RAM. In fact, a compiler's job is exactly to know which variables are in which register at a point in execution, and handle operations on variables thus based on these registers.